# Crop image without scaling or resizing with add_image_size()

Tags: images

Both of these tend to shrink the image and then crop it to the dimensions listed.

What I want is to just crop out the center of the image at 475 x 310

```
add_image_size( 'test', 475, 310, array( 'center', 'center' ) );
add_image_size( 'test2', 475, 310, true );
```

BTW I'm using the regenerate-thumbnails plugin to recreate all the images after I make a new add_image_size() deceleration.

Here is an image 1400 x 788 pixels, where I added a pink box directly in the center which is 475 x 310 pixels
[image]

I've uploaded the image to though my post. Rather than what I want which is crop the image at the pink box it is first scaled down and then cropped to the smaller dimension. Seen below is the new image from my wp-content/uploads directory produced from `add_image_size( 'test', 475, 310, array( 'center', 'center' ) );` also the same result when I change that bit to `add_image_size( 'test', 475, 310, TRUE );`
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You cant do that with the `add_image_size()` function, after a lot of research and digging in the core files, what the `Hard Crop` option of the `add_image_size()` function actually does is resize the image using the lower dimension, then **it will crop the size specified**

by example if you create a new image size:

```
add_image_size( 'test2', 475, 310, true );
```

and upload an image like this one:

[image]

it will resize the image using the `height` `310` (since is the lower value) keeping the aspect ratio, like this:

[image]

then it will proceed to crop the image using the resized image, based in the position that was send or the default `center , center`, the red square overlapping is the size `475, 310` and is the area that will be cropped:

[image]

[image]

[image]

it may look like the `top` and `bottom` dont matter, but that is because the image was resized using the `height`, if it was the other way around, the `width` being the lower the image would be tall and the `left` and `right` would look like they dont matter.

To accomplish what you are trying to do, you will need a plugin or a developer who will add the necessary code to your theme, it cant be done right now with the default built-in tools of wordpress.

These functions are the ones that are doing all this:

- [multiresize](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor-gd.php#L223)
- [_resize](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor-gd.php#L182)
- [image_resize_dimensions](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/media.php#L499)

Comment: I added a new image with a box marked in the center with my dimensions from in add_image_size('test2', 475, 310, TRUE); Still the image seems to be scaled down to 475 and then cropped at 310 vertically. This is with regenerating thumbnails and a fresh upload.

Comment: can you add to your question the original image and the resized one wordpress is creating please

Comment: I've edited my question with image descriptions. Hope this helps

Comment: I've tested this now. @DavidLee from my test using center center hard crop to a 300x130 size. It first resizes to 300px wide and then crops the top and bottom of the pic. It doesn't resize to the lowest value. At least not for me.

Comment: yeah, my answer is based on his image, i am guessing that your original image is tall and not wider? (height > width)