# Auto crop images in Wordpress

Tags: php, images

Im brand new to coding in wordpress, usually I use ModX. In ModX there is a plugin called phpthumb which automatically crops images to a specified h and w. How can I achieve this in Wordpress?

Image Code:

```
<?php
$thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnail_id,'featured works');
echo '<div data-src="'.$thumbnail[0].'" alt="[[+name]]"></div>';
?>
```

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `add_image_size` to create your custom [size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) like this:

```
add_image_size( 'featured-works', 220, 180, true );
```

then get it like this:

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnail_id,'featured-works');
```

take into account how the crop works [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256357/crop-image-without-scaling-or-resizing-with-add-image-size/256374#256374)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the add_image_size() function you won't be able to crop items "on-the-fly" like phpthumb. But there are scripts out there you can use for that, here is one of the popular ones - https://github.com/syamilmj/Aqua-Resizer - this one uses URL's for the input though. Personally I would recommend tweaking it a bit to take in attachment "ID's" instead of URL's this way you can use the core functions - wp_get_attachment_metadata(), get_attached_file() and wp_get_attachment_image_src() to return data this way it passes through the WP filters so it can better support 3rd party plugins. Of course there are many using it as is which works very good.

You can also check out this great plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/fly-dynamic-image-resizer/